# Checking if two PHP lists are completely disjoint

Tags: php, list

In PHP, one can use the following function to determine if one list (the child) is a subset of another (the parent):

```
function issubset($child, $parent)
{
        $c = count($child);
        $valid = 1;
        for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
            if(!in_array($child[$i], $parent)) {
                $valid = 0;
                return $valid;
            }
        }
    return $valid;
}
```

A similar but opposite concept is the idea of two lists being *disjoint*, whereby they have no elements in common whatsoever.

For example, the lists 1,2,3,4 and 4,5,6,7 are not disjoint because they have the common element *4*, but the lists 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 are disjoint as they have no elements in common.

How might a function to check disjointness be designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (count(array_intersect($a, $b)) == 0) { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score 4):

```
function disjoint($arr1, $arr2) {
   return (count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)) == 0);
}

function is_subset($parent, $possible_child) {
   return count(array_intersect($parent, $possible_child)) == count($possible_child);
}
```